# Count occurrences of objects in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have the following list:

```
result = [{"name": "a", "number": 1},
{"name": "a", "number": 2},
{"name": "b", "number": 1},
{"name": "a", "number": 1}]
```

Can I turn it into something like:

```
result = [{"name": "a", "number": 1, "count": 2},
{"name": "a", "number": 2},
{"name": "b", "number": 1}]
```

I tried using the Count class but I couldn't make it work with dictionaries.

Comment: @timgeb: it *could* be syntactically correct, if `name, number` are variables with the right types.

Comment: @timgeb edited accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` with list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
[dict(tuple(t) + (('count', c),)) for t, c in Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in result).items()]
```

This returns:

```
[{'number': 1, 'name': 'a', 'count': 2}, {'number': 2, 'name': 'a', 'count': 1}, {'number': 1, 'name': 'b', 'count': 1}]
```

Comment: Subtle error here: you need a `frozenset` since key may not be in order

Comment: @OlivierMelançon can you explain? I do not understand the error

Comment: @user6251216 in Python 3.6- dict are not ordered, thus if `d1 = {'name': 'a', 'number': 1}` and `d2 = {'name': 'a', 'number': 1}` you have `d1 == d2`, but it might be that `tuple(d1.items()) != tuple(d2.items())` due to the order of iteration. In Python 3.6+ the problem becomes that the order matters and thus if `d1 = {'name': 'a', 'number': 1}` and `d2 = {'number': 1, 'name': 'a'}` you again have `d1 == d2`, but `tuple(d1.items()) != tuple(d2.items())` due to ordering. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535931/5079316) to see how I used `frozenset` instead of `tuple`.

Comment: Thus the above code does work, but thanks to an *implementation* detail of the order of iteration of your dicts (they all have the same hash table), not a language feature. This means it might not work if you ever have a dict that had a key deleted at any point or many other cornercases: this would lead to an incredibly hard to track bug, so I recommend you take the habit of using frozenset and not tuple to compare immutable representation of dicts.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Point taken. I've updated my answer accordingly then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

THis will create a empty dictionary with keys from unique elements in result and initialise all default values to 0.

```
_dict = dict.fromkeys(set([e["name"] for e in result]), 0)
output: {'b': 0, 'a': 0}
```

This will count the number of element in result for the keys present in _dict.

```
[_dict.update({element["name"]: _dict[element["name"]]+1}) for element in result]
```

Since your "number" is same for whole list,

```
[{"name": key, "number": 1, "count": _dict[key]}  for key in _dict.keys()]
output:[{'name': 'b', 'number': 1, 'count': 1},
  {'name': 'a', 'number': 1, 'count': 2}]
```

if number is not same for all the keys, 
remove all the duplicate dicts from the result list.

```
no_dups = [i for n, i in enumerate(result) if i not in result[n + 1:]]
output: [{'name': 'b', 'number': 1}, {'name': 'a', 'number': 1}]
```

create another dict with values as their number :

```
new = {} 
[new.update({i["name"]: i["number"]}) for i in b]
```

Repeat the last step, like this

```
[{"name": key, "number": new[key], "count": _dict[key]}  for key in _dict.keys()]
```

Comment: Can it be more generic, for when I don't have the field names?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `collections.Counter` to count dictionaries by `('name', 'number')`, then add counts conditional on the count being greater than 1. This can be achieved using a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

keys = ('name', 'number')
c = Counter(map(itemgetter(*keys), L))

res = [{**dict(zip(keys, k)), **({'count': v} if v > 1 else {})} \
       for k, v in c.items()]
```

Result:

```
[{'count': 2, 'name': 'a', 'number': 1},
 {'name': 'a', 'number': 2},
 {'name': 'b', 'number': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` class relies on your objects being hashable to count them. Thus, a work-around could be to cast your dictionaries to their immutable equivalents.

The immutable equivalent of a `dict` is a `frozenset` (to account for unorderness of `dict`) of `tuple`.

You can then count then and form back a list of dictionaries from the counter.

```
from collections import Counter

result = [{"name": "a", "number": 1},
    {"name": "a", "number": 2},
    {"name": "b", "number": 1},
    {"name": "a", "number": 1}]

frozen_result = map(lambda d: frozenset(d.items()), result)

count = Counter(frozen_result)

new_result = [dict(k, count=v) for k, v in count.items()]

print(new_result)
```

### Output

```
[{'number': 1, 'name': 'a', 'count': 2},
 {'number': 2, 'name': 'a', 'count': 1},
 {'name': 'b', 'number': 1, 'count': 1}]
```